# How to present a giant JSON file in most efficient way possible (1.8) Gb

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

I am creating a system which error checks ARM-scripts and stores the results in a json file (for efficient parsing for future projects). My problem lies in the sheer size of the json file and need to know if anyone has any cleaver solution to present the json file.

- The code runs through azure functions on an http trigger, at first i presented the result in the response message, but when the file got bigger, the site crashed all the time.

One method which i am working on now is to create an html file which contains the data and only shows i.e. 1000 lines every time the user clicks a button. Would this be a waste of time, considering the users ability to search, copy etc? Is there a better solution which could be implemented in c#?

- Can the solution be done in a C# class
- Could it be done straight in the http trigger class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does "present" mean? Are you showing it to the user? In that case I'd probably give up -- noone's going to read thousands and thousands of lines of JSON. Think about what the you want the user to get out of it, and design something to better suit their needs.

Comment: Just to put this into some sort of context: The Lord of the Rings is about 190,000 words, which at 5 characters/word is about 950,000 characters, or 950kB (assuming ASCII). You're asking the user to read / scan through **twenty** entire Lord of the Rings triologies on a single page. Not going to happen.

Comment: @canton7 Thank you for your comment. You make a fair point. The reason for showing the user the content of the json files is to allow the user to be able to correct the errors in the components and to set new rules for future errors.

Comment: They're never going to *find* any errors by staring at upwards 20,000 pages of text. You need to think about what sorts of things they're actually looking for, and give them better tools to find them

Comment: @canton7 The errors are already found and listed in the json file. However the errors are based on their specifications, which can change.

Comment: Then think of ways of showing them errors without showing them the rest of the JSON file

Comment: @canton7 I suggested that but they wanted to be able to have both options. Which i have managed to do, but the main problem is the size of the json.

Comment: There's no way that someone is knowingly asking to be shown 20 large novels worth of json. You have a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: I hate to say, given the quality of managers of all levels it is totally POSSIBLE that someone thinks this is a sane scenario. Common sense is absurdly absent on SOME managers (not all, granted, but there are a LOT of managers). The next request then would be to split the file and show them to 100 people at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1000 lines every time the user clicks a button. Would this be a waste of time

Yes. ANYTHING that involves a human is garbage when you talk of config files of 1gb - particualarly if this does not involve any sort of search function and involves human eyeball scanning. It will NOT work, unless you talk of something like a header (i.e. top of the file). Period. That is a solution that works - for some sort of human cyborg that does not exist.

> Is there a better solution which could be implemented in c#?

I dare saying there is no good solution. Some sort of editor showing the json alternatively as tree with a LOT of search functions AND some sort of path functoin would POSSIBLY be better but also a LOT of work. The problem is that a 1gb json file is not something you can have any overview in, period. Humans being what they are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is much appreciated.